# Oracle APEX - is there a way to find out if a dynamic action or a process are in use

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

Is there a way in Oracle APEX to find out whether a particular dynamic action was ever used and whether a particular process ever ran?

Update: to make the question less broad, let's say there is a dynamic action called "DA 1" and I need to see if it has ever been used. Also there is a process named, let's say, "Status Change", how can I see if it has ever been run or is it dead in the water

Comment: A very broad question, but you may be interested in apex_workspace_activity_logs

Comment: I might look at the trigger condition on the DA and use that to infer if the DA has ever fired. e.g. if it fires when an item is not null, and I find rows saved in the database that have a value, then I might infer that the DA probably fired for the users who created those records.

Answer (score 1):

These are two very different things.

Processes are PL/SQL processes that run server-side. Enable debugging mode, which can be done through the URL or the menu at the bottom of the page when you're logged in as a developer, then either reload or submit your page. Then click View Debug, find the entry for the page load/submit you just performed and your process will be listed in the output.

Dynamic Actions are small Javascript routines that run in the browser. Again, if you load the page with debugging active, then open the developer tools for your browser (usually F12), if your DA runs, there will be an entry in the console.

Comment: I didn't understand the question that way; it is not about *debugging* (and viewing what's going with the page right now), but - if there's a process named "my_process", created along with the page 3 weeks ago, the OP wants to know whether that process was ever ran since it was created (i.e. during the last 3 weeks).

Comment: Oh, well, unless you've enabled some sort of logging (OraOpenSource Logger) or can infer it from usage data (like a process that runs every time a page loads), I don't think so.

Comment: My thoughts exactly.

Comment: maybe you can find somethin in these views  "apex_activity_log" and "APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_PROC". 
I guess you can not get some log information about the dynamic actions that run on the client side. 
Also, in the upper right corner you will find a menu with the option "activity monitor", maybe there is something useful there too.